# Windows program running at high integrity level without admin right

Tags: security, window, uac

I have got a problem with Windows Integrity Mechanism.

I'm using a software called [Overwolf](http://www.overwolf.com/)

And noticed that one of it's process is running at high integrity level, but not running width admin right.

[image]

After some google, still did not get clear.

So, how to run a program with high integrity level but just as a normal user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I get the answer.

First, need to set link flag when build the program, set *UAC Bypass UI Protection to* :*/uiAccess='true'*, and *UAC excution level* to: */level='asInvoker'*

Second, the program must be signed width a trusted Certification.

At last, the program binary must be placed at system or program file directory.